# Concatenating fields into a new field-QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, concatenation

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm trying to use the field calculator to concatenate multiple fields into one new. All fields are identified as strings.

My expression:
`concatenate(  "Building"  || '-' ||   "Floor"  || '-' || "Area2" || '-' ||  "Room Numbe"  )`

Expected Results:  `6-01-A-02`

Actual results:
`6-01-A-026-01-A-016-01-A-096-01-A-106-01-A-086-01-A-066-01-A-05`

Basically the calculator is concatenating all records across the above fields until reaching the character limit. I'm not sure how to only concatenate by record.

Answer (score 3):

`concatenate()` works on all records and merge them.

To work on a single record, you can use the concatenation operator `||`

```
 "Building" || '-' || "Floor" || '-' || "Area2" || '-' || "Room Numbe"
```

or you can use the `concat()` function

```
concat("Building" , '-' , "Floor" , '-' , "Area2" , '-' , "Room Numbe" )
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried both of these before and was getting a NULL value in the preview. I think it was just because I was editing multiple features. Upon further investigation, it did work as expected.